# Concatenate numpy array with list

Tags: python, numpy

I want to concatenate numpy array with list.
like this:

```
trainClass = np.ones(len(allDataList[0])).tolist()
trainArray = tfIdfsListTrain.toarray()
np.concatenate( (trainArray, trainClass))
```

but I don't know how do I do it.

Comment: Your array is `numpy.array`? Your list is named `list`? Please provide some sample data, and you better do not name your variables `list`, etc.

Comment: What's the problem?  Turn your list into an array and pass it to `concatenate`.  Or let `concatenate` do it for you.  If there is an error it probably has to do with a mismatch in shapes and dimensions.

Comment: @hpaulj shape of array is (2500, 8600) and len of list is 2500

Comment: So, are you looking for `hstack` or something of the sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your list, when turned into an array, doesn't have the right number of dimensions.  Let me illustrate:

```
In [323]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [324]: alist = list(range(3))
In [325]: np.concatenate((arr,alist))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-325-9b72583c40de> in <module>()
----> 1 np.concatenate((arr,alist))

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
In [326]: arr.shape
Out[326]: (3, 4)
```

`concatenate` turns any list inputs into arrays:

```
In [327]: np.array(alist).shape
Out[327]: (3,)
```

`arr` is 2d, so this array needs to be 2d as well:

```
In [328]: np.array(alist)[:,None].shape
Out[328]: (3, 1)
In [329]: np.concatenate((arr, np.array(alist)[:,None]), axis=1)
Out[329]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  0],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  1],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11,  2]])
```

It is easy to concatenate a (3,4) array with a (3,1) array on the last dimension.

I get the impression that a lot of people are jumping into machine learning code (`tensorflow`, `keras`, `sklearn`) without understanding some of the basics of numpy arrays, such as shape and dimensions.

Comment: your last comment is so true, earlier I was using everything as a black box to get ahead in the deep learing craze, but that got me no where, luckily I had a good mentor who is guiding me step by step. I'm thoroughly learning the basics before jumping into any deep learning.